# Neo4J - Conditionally setting value in merge

Tags: neo4j, merge, set, conditional-statements

In Neo4J I am creating nodes using "merge" for example -

```
MERGE (p: Person {id: 'testId1234' }) RETURN p
```

Now if understand this correctly a Node P will be created if one doesn't exist with id 'testId1234'. Now I want to set a property  `eligible_for_vote` only if the person's age was above 18, how can I do that?

When I am inserting a node in the graph I do have access to their age. But I don't know how can I use `SET` conditionally along with `MERGE`

In short, I am trying to do something like this -

```
MERGE (p: Person {id: 'testId1234'})
SET 
if age >= 18
  p.eligible_for_vote = true
end
p.age = 18
RETURN p
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Where is `age` coming from? Did you mean `if p.age >= 18`? and after the end did you mean to set the age to 18 in all cases?

Comment: Yes my current merge query looks like this -
    
    MERGE (p: Person {id: 'testId1234'})
    SET p.age = 18
    RETURN p

Comment: So do you want to only set the age to 18 when creating the node as a default, and also set whether they're eligible to vote or not based on their age?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this fits all your requirements, but hopefully it will help in any case.

```
MERGE (p: Person {id: 'testId1234'})
ON CREATE SET p.age = 18, p.eligible_for_vote = true
ON MATCH SET p.eligible_for_vote = p.age >= 18
RETURN p
```

The ON MATCH and ON CREATE clauses are conditionally invoked depending on if the MERGE resulted in creation of a new node or matching existing node(s), but you are only allowed to use SET operations for either of them

Comment: This is great ! I didn't know that you could use "ON MATCH" and "ON CREATE" together like this. Thank you

Comment: @MadEyeMoody85 If you create the person at age 18, than `age >= 18` should always evaluate to true (I wish I could get younger)... you can pass age as a parameter to the cypher though, in which case you can just do the `SET p.age={age}, p.eligible_for_vote = {age} >= 18`, as both of those probably need to be set on match or create anyways (since you don't know the old value, and both probably need to be updated together). On that note, you probably shouldn't store eligible_for_vote, since the value of that is a function (dynamic value).

Comment: @Tezra that's good to know that I could use parameters in the queries. I think the solution that @InverseFalcon mentioned fits my use case better. `eligible_for_vote` was just for example. But yes I totally agree